# Как затемнить и деактивировать экран

Tags: java, android, activity, layout

У меня в приложении главный экран это GoogleMap на весь экран.
Также стоит слушатель на наличие подключения к интернету.

Нужно:

Затемнить экран и сделать его неактивным (некликабельным) пока не появится соединение.

Есть какие либо варианты реализации?

Comment: рисуете тёмно-прозрачный layout поверх, убираете его, когда появляется подключение

Comment: И? Если у юзера не будет интернета то он просто удалить ваше приложение, подумав что оно зависло. И это вообще идёт против UX. Лучше показывайте вместо карты какой-то текст типа "Нет подключения", а лучше с картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант:

В `layout` кладете кликабельную `View` черного цвета с некоторой прозрачностью:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:translationZ="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

При отсутствии интернета, показываете ее:

```
mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

При наличии – скрываете:

```
mShadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Можно сделать анимацию по альфе для плавного появления этой `View` на экране:

```
private void showShadowView() {
    mShadowView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ValueAnimator shadowViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mShadowView, "alpha", 0, 0.7f);
    shadowViewAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    shadowViewAnimator.start();
}

private void hideShadowView() {
    ValueAnimator shadowViewAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mShadowView, "alpha", 0.7f, 0);
    shadowViewAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    shadowViewAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            mShadowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });
    shadowViewAnimator.start();
}
```